# Prove that $(C_{00},\|\cdot\|)_{\ell^2}$ is not a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

How can we prove that $(C_{00},\|\cdot\|)_{\ell^2}$ is not a Banach space?

How  can  we  find  counter  example  for  this  problem?

Comment: Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n {1\over i}e_i$.

Comment: can  you  explain  it  please?

Comment: $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. But, it's not convergent: suppose $x_n\rightarrow x\in c_{00}$. Choose $n$ such that the $n$'th coordinate of $x$ is $0$. Then show $\Vert x_m-x\Vert \ge 1/n$ for all $m\ge n$.

Comment: I  could not  catch. how  could  you  define  the  sequence  what is  e_i?

Comment: we  have  to  take  x_{n}  from  c_{00}  dont  we?

Comment: $e_i$ is the standard $i$'th unit vector. So $x_n=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots, 1/n, 0,0,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me prove a stronger claim: $c_{00}$ is not a Banach space under *any* norm. Indeed, we can write

$$c_{00} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\mbox{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$$

where $e_n$ denotes the sequence which is everywhere null except the $n$th place where it takes value 1. No matter what norm we put on $c_{00}$ the spaces $\mbox{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ will be always closed because they are finite-dimensional. Now, if $c_{00}$ were a Banach space, by Baire's theorem, one of the subspaces $\mbox{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ would have non-empty interior. This is impossible as [proper subspaces always have empty interior](http://planetmath.org/propersubspacesofatopologicalvectorspacehaveemptyinterior).

Comment: This is a very nice, simple and elegant application of Baire Categories. Suddenly, I am able to construct an infinity of incomplete spaces!!! Thank you! I will take note! :-)